# Accumulo Iterator Not Being Called

Tags: accumulo

I am learning Accumulo and want to add my own Iterator to a scan.  My Iterator extends WrappingIterator, and I add it to my scanner (priority 10, MyIterator.class), but none of the methods nor the public no-args constructor ever gets called.  I am using MiniAccumulo cluster and set breakpoints in the constructor and other public methods of my Iterator, but they are never hit.

Ultimately what I am trying to do (beyond learning about Iterators):
- I want Accumulo to maintain versions of my changes so I have configured it mic, majc, and scan # of versions to MAX_INT
- When scanning across a range of keys, there are times when I only want the most recent for each key in the range (not the full history returned to the client).
- My thought was to write an Iterator that could return the latest key/value pair for each item in the range where latest = the key with the latest timestamp value for each in the range.

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't well suited to StackOverflow because it doesn't have a single answer, and more details are needed to figure out what is going wrong in your case. I recommend asking on Accumulo's user mailing list instead. user@accumulo.apache.org

Comment: I figured what the problem was. It turns out that my Iterator was being called. The reason it was not hitting any breakpoints is that it is executed in another process (instance of the JVM); a tablet server.  Once I realized that even MiniAccumuloCluster starts a separate process for the tablet server, I figured out how to get the debug ports from the MiniAccumuloCluster and remotely debug my Iterator from Eclipse.
Thanks for the suggestion about posting to the Accumulo forum, I'll do so in the future.